# How do I update my NXT firmware using EV3 software

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, ev3

The new EV3 software tells me to update my firmware on the NXT.  When I go to the tools menu and select update firmware it tells me the NXT brick can not support this function.

Comment: Same problem here. Looks like on the NXT you need to move the firmware file to a directory in the lego mindstorm software directory and click on update firmware in the NXT software.

Comment: I don't really believe that ev3 firmware can be ran on NXT, but... Has anyone tried to copy ev3 firmware and import it with NXT software?

Answer (score 3):

EV3 software will not download firmware to the NXT brick.  For that you need the NXT-G software and a downloaded firmware file from Lego.  1.31 is the latest version.

So if you're running EV3 on NXT, you shouldn't throw out the NXT-G software. Once in a while, it's still needed.

Comment: In case you lose the CD, here is a link to an ISO image: http://esd.lego.com.edgesuite.net/digitaldelivery/mindstorms/6ecda7c2-1189-4816-b2dd-440e22d65814/public/MINDSTORMS%20NXT%20Retail%20MacWin.iso